# Fragment scrolls while watching videos [YouTube API]

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I want to play YouTube-video in one of the fragments ([YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/)). A class that implements the video fragment looks like this:

```
public class VideoFragment extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment {
    private YouTubePlayer activePlayer;

    public static VideoFragment newInstance(String url) {

        VideoFragment playerYouTubeFrag = new VideoFragment();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("url", url);

        playerYouTubeFrag.setArguments(bundle);

        playerYouTubeFrag.init();

        return playerYouTubeFrag;
    }

    private void init() {

        initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
                activePlayer = player;
                activePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
                if (!wasRestored) {
                    activePlayer.loadVideo(getArguments().getString("url"), 0);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        activePlayer.pause();
    }
}
```

Then I replace a `FrameLayout` in another fragment:

```
    public class InfoFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // ... some code ...

        VideoFragment videoFragment = VideoFragment.newInstance("video_id");
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.videoLayout, videoFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

It works, but while watching a video screen scrolls up and the video is paused.

So, my questions are:

1. Why does the screen scrolling when viewing?
2. If I am not mistaken, the video playback should be in a separate thread because the player initialization retarding the main thread. Is there any nuances that should be considered in this case?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Do you mean that the view scrolls by itself when you play the video?

Comment: @ChrisK. yes, you are right. Screen focus jumps to the area which is above the video and the video is stopped.

Comment: you can use requestFocus() on the view you want

Comment: @ChrisK. I tried to do it before `FrameLayout` replacing: `frameLayout.requestFocus();`, but this doesn't solve the problem.